# Como passar estrutura para função?

Tags: c, funções, struct

> Uma agência de uma cidade do interior tem, no máximo, 10.000 clientes. Elabore um algoritmo que possa entrar com número da conta, nome e saldo de cada cliente. O algoritmo deve imprimir todas as contas, os respectivos saldos e uma das mensagens: positivo / negativo. A digitação termina quando se digita -999 para número da conta ou quando chegar a 10.000. Ao final, o algoritmo deverá mostrar o total de clientes com saldo negativo, o total de clientes da agência e o saldo da agência.)

Pois bem, logo pensei em usar uma estrutura de dados com as variáveis necessárias para armazenar as informações solicitadas ao cliente N vezes, cada vez de um cliente diferente. Pois bem, eis meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


    typedef struct clientes
    {
        char nome[50];
        int conta;
        int saldo;

    } clientes;


    struct clientes cadastro_cliente (clientes x);


    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

        struct clientes x[1000];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cadastro_cliente(clientes x[i]);
        }
    }


    struct clientes cadastro_cliente (clientes x);
    {
        printf("Insira o nome completo do titular da conta: ");
        scanf("%s", &x.nome);

        printf("Insira o número da conta: ");
        scanf("%i", &x.conta);

        printf("Insira o saldo da conta: ");
        scanf("%i", &x.saldo);
    }
```

O código me retorna um erro ao executar, um erro já esperado pois não tenho conhecimento de como passar uma estrutura para uma função que seria chamada N vezes. Cheguei a este ponto assistindo um vídeo no YouTube porém não dá para tirar dúvidas. Como iria passar uma estrutura para função e chamar a mesma na `main()`sempre que solicitado pelo usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de crescer é aprender de forma estruturada. Principalmente em C que é cheia de detalhes. Se em qualquer linguagem tem que saber exatamente como tudo funciona, não pode achar que porque funciona está certo, em C isso é absurdamente mais importante.

Não sei por onde está aprendendo, mas cuidado com fontes voluntariosas que não sabem e tentem ensinar outras pessoas. A internet está cheio disso. Aqui você está um pouco melhor porque na maioria dos assuntos tem outras pessoas experientes que avaliam as respostas, mesmo assim nada é 100% confiável.

O código tem vários erros e nem compila. Melhorei assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[50];
    int conta;
    int saldo;
} Cliente;

void cadastro_cliente(Cliente *cliente) {
    printf("\nInsira o nome completo do titular da conta: ");
    scanf("%49s", cliente->nome);
    printf("\nInsira o número da conta: ");
    scanf("%d", &cliente->conta);
    printf("\nInsira o saldo da conta: ");
    scanf("%d", &cliente->saldo);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    Cliente clientes[1000] = {{ .nome = "", .conta = 0, .saldo = 0 }};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) cadastro_cliente(&clientes[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) printf("\n%s - %d", clientes[i].nome, clientes[i].conta);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/INXHMD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mhwfsylx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/StructParameter.c).

Note que fiz algumas melhorias sutis, inclusive de nomenclatura, preste atenção em cada caractere.

A passagem precisa ser por referência para que os dados sejam colocados na estrutura. Normalmente uma estrutura é um tipo por valor e copia o dado tendo outro objeto, quando passa a referência da estrutura não há cópia e para todos os efeitos a estrutura está no local original que ela foi criada, portanto na `main()` neste código. É o mesmo processo usado no `scanf()`, que por sinal um deles estava errado.

Eu preferi inicializar todos os elementos do *array*. Fica um pouco mais lento, mas é mais seguro. Aí depende de uma série de fatores para escolher o que é melhor.

Cuidado porque isso funciona assim, mas se mudar algumas coisas esse código pode ter outros problemas que não interagirão bem. Tem muitas coisas no código que funcionam como aprendizado básico, mas em código real não seria feito assim (um dos motivos que não gosto desses cursos no YouTube, pelo menos deveriam avisar que aquilo não é como se faz na realidade).

Procure aqui mais sobre o assunto, tem bastante coisa já avaliada.